# Why is linq slow in c#

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq, clr

I suddenly became curious about linq performance and ran some test.

Below is my test code and the result was pretty surprising.

Can anyone how linq work and why slower than TryOut ?

```
Public class TestObject
{
 ....
 ....
 //this class contain many members 
 bool deleted;
 ....
}

class Program
{
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, TestObject> testDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, TestObject>();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
 //testDictionary is initialized in ohter code and is likely to have 10000 elements.
  RandomTest(0);
  RandomTest(1);
  Console.ReadKey();
}

static void RandomTest(int k)
{
    int count = 10000;
    List<string> randomId = new List<string>();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
         int randomNumber = rnd.Next(0, testDictionary.Count());
         randomId.Add(testDictionary.ElementAt(randomNumber).key);
    }
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start(); 

    if (k == 0)
    {

         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
         {
             var res = checkid(randomId[i]);
         }
    }
    else if (k == 1)
    {
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
         {
             var res = checkid2(randomId[i]);
         }
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time : " + sw.Elapsed);
}
static bool checkid(string id)
{
    TestObject t;
    return !testDictionary.TryGetValue(id, out t) ?
          false : t.deleted ?
          false : true;
}
static bool checkid2(string id)
{
    return testDictionary.Any(t => t.key == id && !t.Value.deleted)? true : false;
}
```

I ran these 2 methods 10000 times and result shows like below

For checkid method, it mostly took less than 00:00:00.002.

For checkid2 method, it mostly took between 00:00:02.2 and 00:00:02.4.

This is a huge difference.

Is this because checkid2 method checks deleted variable too even if key is not equal to Id while checkid method checks deleted variable only when it found the corresponding key?

Comment: Because linq is not using hashtable of dictionary. Its basically o(n) rather than o(1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Dictionary.TryGetValue` is using hashing to locate the element so it's an *O(1)* operation.

`Dictionary.Any` will iterate over the collection trying to find one which matches the condition. That's *O(n)*.

In general - LINQ will be little bit slower than hand-crafting loops using `for`/`foreach`, but the performance difference in most cases doesn't matter. What you're experiencing is not LINQ being slow here, it's `Dictionary<T>.TryGetValue` being fast because of it's internal structure being optimized for key-based searching. If you change it do be a `List<T>` and write a `for` loop to do the same search in linear fashion (like LINQ does under the covers) you'll see the difference become much smaller.

Answer (score 1):

@MarcinJuraszek answered correct. But I want to add some related LINQ info to complete the answer. Yes the main difference with the behavior of hashing vs iterating is clear, but there is more you need to know about LINQ in .NET

For `checkid` the IL looks like this:

```
IL_0000: ldsfld class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2<string, class ConsoleApp5.TestObject> ConsoleApp5.Program::testDictionary
IL_0005: ldarg.0
IL_0006: ldloca.s t
IL_0008: callvirt instance bool class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2<string, class ConsoleApp5.TestObject>::TryGetValue(!0, !1&)
IL_000d: brfalse.s IL_001b

IL_000f: ldloc.0
IL_0010: ldfld bool ConsoleApp5.TestObject::deleted
IL_0015: brtrue.s IL_0019

IL_0017: ldc.i4.1
IL_0018: ret

IL_0019: ldc.i4.0
IL_001a: ret

IL_001b: ldc.i4.0
IL_001c: ret
```

It's do exactly what you think is do (what you wrote in the code).

But the `checkid2` do this:

```
IL_0000: newobj instance void ConsoleApp5.Program/'<>c__DisplayClass4_0'::.ctor()
IL_0005: stloc.0
IL_0006: ldloc.0
IL_0007: ldarg.0
IL_0008: stfld string ConsoleApp5.Program/'<>c__DisplayClass4_0'::id
IL_000d: ldsfld class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2<string, class ConsoleApp5.TestObject> ConsoleApp5.Program::testDictionary
IL_0012: ldloc.0
IL_0013: ldftn instance bool ConsoleApp5.Program/'<>c__DisplayClass4_0'::'<checkid2>b__0'(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2<string, class ConsoleApp5.TestObject>)
IL_0019: newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2<string, class ConsoleApp5.TestObject>, bool>::.ctor(object, native int)
IL_001e: call bool [System.Core]System.Linq.Enumerable::Any<valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2<string, class ConsoleApp5.TestObject>>(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0>, class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<!!0, bool>)
IL_0023: brtrue.s IL_0027

IL_0025: ldc.i4.0
IL_0026: ret

IL_0027: ldc.i4.1
IL_0028: ret
```

And the "real" check id logic is here (under `<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<checkid2>b__0`):

```
IL_0000: ldarga.s t
IL_0002: call instance !0 valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2<string, class ConsoleApp5.TestObject>::get_Key()
IL_0007: ldarg.0
IL_0008: ldfld string ConsoleApp5.Program/'<>c__DisplayClass4_0'::id
IL_000d: call bool [mscorlib]System.String::op_Equality(string, string)
IL_0012: brfalse.s IL_0024

IL_0014: ldarga.s t
IL_0016: call instance !1 valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2<string, class ConsoleApp5.TestObject>::get_Value()
IL_001b: ldfld bool ConsoleApp5.TestObject::deleted
IL_0020: ldc.i4.0
IL_0021: ceq
IL_0023: ret

IL_0024: ldc.i4.0
IL_0025: ret
```

This code creating a new compiler generated type `<>c__DisplayClass4.0`, saving the `id` as a class member, creating delegate to `<>c__DisplayClass4_0'::'<checkid2>b__0` that get KeyValuePair and return bool and call to Any to use this delegate.

Add to this, the fact that Any is O(n) and Dictionary is O(1) - like Marcin wrote - and you got your answer.